# Get current source line number

Tags: errors, debugging, source

How can I get the current .tex source line number? I want to use it to generate useful error messages in a package I am writing.

There are some errors that can only be detected at the end of the document, so I want to create a command that checks for them and tells at what line the error was made. To do that, I need to be able to save the source line number in the command that was misapplied.

Preferably a command that can be used like `\sourcelineno` in this example:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\newcommand \showlineno {line \sourcelineno}

\begin{document}

You are now at \showlineno.

This paragraph starts at \showlineno, and 
some more text,
and runs until \showlineno. 

\end{document}
```

where the output would be

```
You are now at line 6.

This paragraph starts at line 8, and some more text, and runs until line 10.
```

Comment: Would `\number\inputlineno` instead of `\sourcelineno` do the trick?

Comment: @egreg: yes. I hadn't found out about `\inputlineno` yet.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use a variation of the kernel's `\on@line`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\ifnum\inputlineno=\m@ne
\let\showlineno\@empty
\else
\def\showlineno{ line \the\inputlineno}
\fi
\makeatother

\begin{document}

You are now at \showlineno.

This paragraph starts at \showlineno, and 
some more text,
and runs until \showlineno.

on input line \the\inputlineno

\end{document}
```

Comment: Great! `\inputlineno` is what I was looking for.

Comment: Gonzalo, do you know how to put this command on the whole document? I mean, there is a way to use automatically this command (`\showlineno`) on every line of the source? Mi objective is to get something like this: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/261571/marginpar-for-all-the-document

Answer (score 0):

A LuaLaTeX variation on Gonzalo's answer, as an introductory example of `\directlua` usage.

```
\documentclass{article}

\def\showlineno{
  line \directlua{tex.print(tex.inputlineno)}%
}

\begin{document}

You are now at \showlineno.

This paragraph starts at \showlineno, and 
some more text,
and runs until \showlineno.

on input line \the\inputlineno

\end{document}
```

The weird line numbers are not managed.